SQLAlchemy2 ORM session.add not performing multi-value insert
As an example, I have the following..
class Base( DeclarativeBase ):
    pass

class A( Base ):
    __tablename__   = "A"

    id:         Mapped[ int ] = mapped_column( primary_key = True )
    a_value:    Mapped[ str ] = mapped_column( String( 32 ) )
    b_list:     Mapped[ List[ "B" ] ] = relationship( "B" )

class B( Base ):
    __tablename__   = "B"
    __table_args__  = (
        ForeignKeyConstraint( [ "a_id" ], [ "A.id" ] ),
    )

    id:         Mapped[ int ]   = mapped_column( primary_key = True )
    a_id:       Mapped[ int ]
    b_value:    Mapped[ str ]   = mapped_column( String( 32 ) )

Followed by the this which created a list of A's each containing a list of B's
a_list = []
for a_id in range( 0, 3 ):
    a = A( a_value = f"A_{a_id}" )
    for b_id in range( 0, 3 ):
        a.b_list.append(
            B( b_value = f"B_{a_id}-{b_id}" )
        )
    a_list.append( a )

Then I use session.add to put them in the database...
with Session( engine ) as session, session.begin():
    for a in a_list:
        session.add( a )

When I run this I get the following which clearly shows that it's not performing a multi-values insert but inserting each row one at a time.
BEGIN (implicit)
INSERT INTO `A` (a_value) VALUES (%(a_value)s)
[generated in 0.01637s] {'a_value': 'A_0'}
INSERT INTO `A` (a_value) VALUES (%(a_value)s)
[cached since 0.04846s ago] {'a_value': 'A_1'}
INSERT INTO `A` (a_value) VALUES (%(a_value)s)
[cached since 0.07575s ago] {'a_value': 'A_2'}
INSERT INTO `B` (a_id, b_value) VALUES (%(a_id)s, %(b_value)s)
[generated in 0.01316s] {'a_id': 1, 'b_value': 'B_0-0'}
INSERT INTO `B` (a_id, b_value) VALUES (%(a_id)s, %(b_value)s)
[cached since 0.04103s ago] {'a_id': 1, 'b_value': 'B_0-1'}
INSERT INTO `B` (a_id, b_value) VALUES (%(a_id)s, %(b_value)s)
[cached since 0.06817s ago] {'a_id': 1, 'b_value': 'B_0-2'}
INSERT INTO `B` (a_id, b_value) VALUES (%(a_id)s, %(b_value)s)
[cached since 0.09477s ago] {'a_id': 2, 'b_value': 'B_1-0'}
INSERT INTO `B` (a_id, b_value) VALUES (%(a_id)s, %(b_value)s)
[cached since 0.1232s ago] {'a_id': 2, 'b_value': 'B_1-1'}
INSERT INTO `B` (a_id, b_value) VALUES (%(a_id)s, %(b_value)s)
[cached since 0.1506s ago] {'a_id': 2, 'b_value': 'B_1-2'}
INSERT INTO `B` (a_id, b_value) VALUES (%(a_id)s, %(b_value)s)
[cached since 0.177s ago] {'a_id': 3, 'b_value': 'B_2-0'}
INSERT INTO `B` (a_id, b_value) VALUES (%(a_id)s, %(b_value)s)
[cached since 0.2036s ago] {'a_id': 3, 'b_value': 'B_2-1'}
INSERT INTO `B` (a_id, b_value) VALUES (%(a_id)s, %(b_value)s)
[cached since 0.2371s ago] {'a_id': 3, 'b_value': 'B_2-2'}
COMMIT

I'd have expected something like
INSERT INTO `B` (a_id, b_value) VALUES ( 1, "B_0-0" ), ( 1, "B_0-1" ), ( 1, "B_0-2" )

So, what settings or approach do I need to change to make this insertion more performant and use multi-values inserts..
EDIT
I should have added that I'm using a MySQL v8 database server.

Optimized ORM bulk insert now implemented for all backends other than MySQL

@GordThompson That is amazing.  This whole time I didn't even know sqlalchemy could do batch inserts automatically without using core.  It is completely seamless.    @ScaryAardvark Your exact code produces 2 INSERT statements using postgresql, maybe you could try MariaDB in place of mysql?  Otherwise maybe you could generate the primary keys in python.

@GordThompson. That is very dissapointing but thanks very much for mentiong it.
